# Open some file types in new frame

Tags: window-splitting, pdf-tools, dedicated-windows

I use split-frame (`split-window-right` in setup) for most things but would like Emacs to open **some** file types (specifically PDF files) in a new frame when using `find-file`.

Other files (for example `.org` files) should be opened in split-frame as before. I use pdf-tools for viewing PDFs.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Here is a link to a complex example of how to target a specific frame with buffers or filenames matching a particular regexp:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  If you Google a bit, you'll find simpler examples using the `display-buffer-alist` and also the `special-display-regexps`.  See also the two examples in the manual for some additional ideas:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html

Comment: As @lawlist suggested, see variables `special-display-regexps` and `special-display-buffer-names`. Put the PDF buffers in dedicated windows. Alternatively, can fiddle with `display-buffer-alist`.

Comment: I tried `(add-to-list 'special-display-regexps ".*\.pdf$")` but no luck.